# The complement of a graph G

Tags: graph-theory

I have a homework problem where I have a graph $G$ and I am tasked with proving that at least one of $G$ and $G$ complement is connected. However, I am unclear on the exact meaning of $G$ complement.

For example, let's imagine I have a disconnected graph with four vertices $(V_1, V_2, V_3, \text{and } V_4)$. 
If the edges form a sort of box where the bottom edge is left disconnected, would $G$ complement have that edge filled in along with the cross edges as well? Furthermore, does $G$ complement contain all of the edges in $G$ or just the edges not contained in $G$? Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complement means the graph with same vertices and the missing edges.

**Hint for the problem** If $G$ is connected you are done. If $G$ is disconnected, let $u, v$ be vertices in two different components of $G$.

Then $uv$ is an edge in the complement of $G$. Moreover, if $w$ is any other vertex in $G$, then at least one of $uw, vw$ has to be an edge in the complement. This way you can coonect $w$ to both $u$ and $v$ in the complement, and from here you can prove that the complement is connected.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what you mean by "two different components of G?" So far, I can assume that if u,v are vertices in G that are not connected by an edge, then G complement would contain an edge, thus creating a path from u to v. Furthermore, when you add another vertex in the graph G, like you did with w, you're saying that G complement is always going to have at least 1 of 2 possible edges.

Comment: @StarCute Do you know what a disconnected graph is?

Comment: Yeah, it's when you have at least two vertices that have no edges connecting them in some way.

Answer (score 0):

$G$ complement has exactly the edges not contained in $G$, and $G$ complement has the same vertices as $G$.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, G complement will not have any of the edges in G right? Just the same vertices.

Comment: @StarCute Same vertices and none of the edges. The formal definition of the complement is: $V(\bar{G})=V(G)$ and $uv$ is an edge in $\bar{G}$ if an only if $uv$ is NOT an edge in $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, its complement graph is precisely the graph $(V,V^{(2)}-E)$, where $V^{(2)}$ consists of all 2-subsets of $V$. Thus, the complement graph has the same vertex set as $G$, and its edge set consists exactly of all edges of the complete graph $K_n$ that are not in $G$, where $n=|V|$ is the number of vertices of $G$.

Thus, the complement graph of $G=(V,E)$ consists of exactly $\binom{n}{2} - |E|$ edges, and the total number of edges in $G$ and in its complement will add up to exactly the number of edges of the complete graph $K_n$, i.e. to $\binom{n}{2}$.

To prove that at least one of $G$ or its complement $\overline{G}$ is connected, suppose $G$ is not connected and has connected components $G_1,G_2,\ldots$.  Then in the complement graph every vertex of $G_i$ is connected to every vertex of $G_j$, whenever $i \ne j$.  Thus, $\overline{G}$ is connected.